# Why am I getting weird increments in my for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, increment

I have been testing ways to check individual characters in a string for a numeric value.  I set up a for loop that goes through them, but when I'm logging it to the console, I get a weird response:

```
isNumeric: function(n){
    for(var i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
        console.log("Looping " + i+1);
    }
},
```

So I passed in the value `"10"` to test it.  I get a weird response when I call the function.  I get two logs onto the console (like expected), but it says

```
Looping 01
Looping 11
```

What is going on here? I didn't think that I was concating strings here, but for some reason it thinks I am? I declared i as an integer `var i = 0;` and when you increment it by one, what is it doing?

The only other thing I think it must be doing is logging something else appended to `Looping 0` and `Looping 1`, but I don't think that's the case.

If anyone can please help, this is really bugging me and I can't seem to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is [**left-to-right associative**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Associativity). The expression is evaluated as

```
('Looping ' + i) + 1
```

Is it clearer now why string concatenation is performed? If *any* of the two operands of a `+` operation is a string, string concatenation is performed. `'Looping '` is a string, hence `'Looping ' + i` results in a string.

To change precedence or associativity, you have to use the grouping "operator" (`(...)`).

Answer (score 2):

You mean `console.log("Looping " + (i+1));`
The "1" is being appended as a string.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log("Looping " + i+1);` is being parsed from left to right, as `("Looping " + i) + 1`. Add parentheses in the right spot and it should work:

```
console.log("Looping " + (i+1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating strings, not adding numbers. First, the value of `i` is cast to a string and concatenated to `Looping`, resulting in `Looping 0`. Then, the number `1` is cast to a string and concatenated as well, resulting in what you are seeing: `Looping 01`.

To get the result you want, you can simply put the `i+1` in parentheses.

```
console.log("Looping " + (i+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies in the line where you do the actual logging :

```
console.log("Looping " + i+1);
```

First `"Looping " + i` happens.

Because `"Looping"` is a string, `i` gets cast to a string and appended to `"Looping"`.

The result :

`"Looping 0"`

Then, the `1` gets added the same way.

`"Looping 01"`

If you want to keep this from happening, use parenthesis like so :

```
isNumeric: function(n){
    for(var i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
        console.log("Looping " + (i+1));
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

They are right to add the parentheses, the whole code would be:

```
isNumeric: function(n){
    for(var i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
        console.log("Looping " + (i+1));
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare your results with this:

```
n=[1,2,3,4]

function isnum(n){
    for(var i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
        console.log("Looping " + i+1);
        console.log("Looping " + (i+1));
    }
}

isnum(n);
```

This generates the output:

```
Looping 01
Looping 1
Looping 11
Looping 2
Looping 21
Looping 3
Looping 31
Looping 4
```

In the statement `"Looping " + i+1` what's happening is that `"Looping " + i` is happening first, i being cast to a string value for the concatenation with "Looping ". The `1` is also being cast as a string value for concatentation. By putting parens around the `i+1` we can force `(i+1)` to happen first as addition before being concatenated, so the output is what you would expect.